# find parent repeater from child repeater's dropdownlist selectedindexchange

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I want to find the Parent Repeater, which contains Child Repeater and Child Repeater contains dropdownlist. On SelectedIndexChange of the Drowndownlist I want to find out the Parent Repeater. After finding the parent repeater, I want to find the hiddenfield value inside Parent Repeater. i.e.

Parent Repeater Contains HiddenField and Child Repeater
Child Repeater contains Dropdownlist on this dropdown selected index change event I want to find HiddenField value which is in Parent Repeater.

My Code:

```
        DropDownList myGeneralButton = (DropDownList)sender;
        Repeater item = (Repeater)myGeneralButton.Parent.Parent;

        for (int i = 0; i < item.Items.Count; ++i) 
        {
            HiddenField hdn=  item.Items[i].FindControl("Hdhotelname") as HiddenField;
            string h = hdn.Value;
        }
```

In this hidden field I am getting all the values, but I want a value of that particular index where I am selecting selecting the dropdown.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to search through the `DropDownList`'s `NamingContainer`. The flow should be like this:

> (DropDownList)sender
>  
>   --> NamingContainer(Child RepeaterItem)
>  
>   --> NamingContainer(Child Repeater)
>  
>   --> NamingContainer(Parent  RepeaterItem)
>  
>   --> FindControl"Hdhotelname" (Hdhotelname)

and your code should be like this:

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    var rptChild = ddl.NamingContainer.NamingContainer;//Child Repeater
    if (rptChild != null)
    {
        var rptParentItem = rptChild.NamingContainer;//Parent RepeaterItem
        var hdnfld = rptParentItem.FindControl("Hdhotelname") as HiddenField;
        if (hdnfld != null)
        {
            //Do your tasks
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= (Repeater)ChildRepeater.NamingContainer =>
```

or use it directly in your code-behind without the `<%=` and `=>`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did: DropDownList myGeneralButton = (DropDownList)sender;
            RepeaterItem item = (RepeaterItem)myGeneralButton.Parent.Parent; I also want to find out Hidden Field in the repeater can you please help me

Comment: HiddenField is in Parent Repeater, I want to find that value

Comment: (HiddenField)((RepeaterItem)NestedRepeater.Parent.Parent).FindControl("HiddenInputFieldIDInParent"); <-- Does this accomplish that? I love WebForms because you can do things like that.

Comment: if you're not doing this in the Item_DataBound event... then you would need to use for (int i = 0; i < repeater.Items.Count; ++i) { repeater.Items[i].FindControl("HiddenInputFieldID") as HiddenField }. This will go through each repeater item and get the hidden field.. then you can use .Value to get the value

Comment: I am doing this on ddl_SelectedIndexChanged. Error:Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater'. Code: DropDownList myGeneralButton = (DropDownList)sender;
            Repeater item = (Repeater)myGeneralButton.Parent.Parent;
            HiddenField hdn = (HiddenField)((Repeater)item.Parent.Parent).FindControl("Hdhotelname");

Comment: Thanks, but  (int i = 0; i < repeater.Items.Count; ++i) this is returning names of all Value as many times Item is Repeated, I want the value of that Item only, where I am selecting the value from dropdown.